# Inspect and debug a production Cordova app installed on the device from the app store

Tags: android, ios, cordova, debugging

I'm trying to **debug a Cordova app by inspecting it** remotely using the browser.

Per example, on my iPhone, I could access the webView by **Safari Developer Menu**, or in my Android, using Google Chrome `chrome://inspect`.

It works good when I install the app on the device by the CLI 
`cordova run ios` 
`cordova run android` 
but, when I download the same app **from the store**, where I published it, I can't inspect it anymore, in fact **I can't find it to inspect it** in Chrome/Android nor Safari/iOs.

**Is there a way to inspect the production app?**

How am I supposed to debug it otherwise (e.g. the bug happens only in production)?

Thanks.

Comment: It works like that for security reasons, App Store apps can't be debugged. You can try using weinre or any other remote debugger, but Apple might not approve the app if they notice it.

Comment: i don't understand why did they disable remote debug if i explicitly enable debug in my device settings. to me it looks like a bug. there should be a way to enable debug for production apps. is there a discussion somewhere about it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't verified it on Cordova but I discovered it is possible to debug a production android app by adding

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

to the manifest as an `<application>` tag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer possible to upload a debuggable apk:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable debugging for webviews in android application.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

add above code in main activity file.

more info about remote debugging :

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/

**Note : It is not recommended to turn on debugging on live playstore apps.**